# compare elements of an array

Tags: java, arrays

Hi suppose I have an array of `v1[] = {1, 3, 4, 5}` and `v2[] = {5, 3, 4, 6}`. I want to compare the elements of v1 and v2 and, get the largest value as an output (optimal solution). if V1 and V2 are the length of the array
I tried

```
for(i = 0; i <=n; i++) //for items of an array

for( j = V1; i >= 0; i--) //for items in v1

  for( k = V2; j >= 0; j--) //for itemns in v2

    if(v1[i] <= j && v2[i] <= k)
      int V1 = v1[i];
      int V2 = v2[i];
```

But does not work correctly. Please help.

Comment: You might want to mention which language you're using ...

Comment: You should know that only the line `int V1 = v1[i];` is in your `if` conditional- the line `int V2 = v2[i];` is outside it

Comment: `max(v1 U v2)` is equal to `max(max(v1), max(v2))`

Comment: Can you give some sample output. Do you just want the maximum of the union of both arrays?

Comment: I'm dying inside from the mistakes when iterating through your for-loops...

Comment: i want my output as **v1 = 5 and v2 = 6** because both are the largest item in the arrays.

Comment: @shiro-chan why are you trying to do it that way? Just use two loops.

Comment: I suggest that you write a `max()` method which returns the maximum element of a single array. Then you can call this method with both arrays while only writing the code once to find the maximum value.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the maximum element present from both the array, you can try something like this:

```
int max = v1[0];

for(int index = 1; index < v1.length; index++){
    if(v1[index] > max)
        max = v1[index];
}
System.out.println("v1 = "+max);

max = v2[0];
for(int index = 1; index < v2.length; index++){
    if(v2[index] > max)
        max = v2[index];
}
System.out.println("v2 = "+max);
```

Comment: As stated by the OP in a comment above: `i want my output as v1 = 5 and v2 = 6 because both are the largest item in the arrays`. I have added another answer which separates the maximum values in the different arrays.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg: Thanks for the heads up, I didn't dig deep into the comment section for the question :) Updated!

Answer (score 0):

you could simply sort both the arrays and get the largest (last indexed element)  values and compare them like this

```
int[] v1= {1, 3, 4, 5};
 Arrays.sort(v1);
 int v1Max = v1[v1.length-1];

 int[] v2 = {5, 3, 4, 6};
 Arrays.sort(v2);
 int v2Max = v2[v2.length-1];
 if(v1Max>v2Max) { 
 System.out.println(v1Max);
  }
  if(v2Max>v1Max) {
      System.out.println(v2Max);
   }
```

Comment: I would probably advise not modifying the entire array by imposing a total order just to get the maximum element.

Comment: @oldrinb yes you are right, i was just showing a very basic solution.

Answer (score 0):

As you have stated that you want the maximum of each loop separately, what you are looking for is:

```
int maxInV1 = v1[0];
for(int index = 1; index < v1.length; index++) {
    if(v1[index] > maxInV1) {
        maxInV1 = v1[index];
    }
}

int maxInV2 = v2[0];
for(int index = 1; index < v2.length; index++) {
    if(v2[index] > maxInV2) {
        maxInV2 = v2[index];
    }
}
```

Note that there are more efficient solutions available, but given the overall confusion in your code, I think you should learn this basic way first. I'm sorry to say it but the code you posted in the question was nowhere near a solution because of the many problems in it.

Also note that this is a slightly modified version of the answer by @Sujay, simply using two different variables.

Answer (score -1):

Even if your loops and what not work might work as is (and i really don't know because I didn't want to waste my time...others have already answered the question asked), your loops would never work correctly because of your lack of braces...

Since you have multiple lines inside your for loops and if statement you have to have them..

```
for(i = 0; i <=n; i++) { //for items of an array

    for( j = V1; i >= 0; i--) { //for items in v1

        for( k = V2; j >= 0; j--) { //for itemns in v2

            if(v1[i] <= j && v2[i] <= k) {
                int V1 = v1[i];
                int V2 = v2[i];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is the only way that would get close to working...and I doubt it will even then. I can tell you now that 3 for loops are not required for this problem...

As a matter of fact, @Sujay already gave one way to do it with just 2.

Comment: I can say the same thing as you say in your entire answer with a simple comment: Use braces `{` and `}` for your statements. The rest of your answer is nowhere near helpful.